# Google Distance Matrix API or Google Directions API returning ZERO_RESULTS for two locations from different continents

Tags: google-distancematrix-api, distance-matrix

When searching for distances between two locations from different continents, API is returning ZERO_RESULTS

1.Origin: Otawistraße 40, 13351 Berlin, Germany - place_id ChIJDRnPKt9TqEcRYwjmKskH6gM
2. Destination Las Vegas Convention Center, Paradise Road, Las Vegas, NV, USA - place_id ChIJ5yKvQGbEyIARRrDnL_5KOqk
3. returns {
"destination_addresses": [
"3150 Paradise Rd, Las Vegas, NV 89109, USA"
],
"origin_addresses": [
"Otawistraße 40, 13351 Berlin, Germany"
],
"rows": [
{
"elements": [
{
"status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
]
}
],
"status": "OK"
}

and the examples could go on, basically if the addresses (places) are from 2 different continents, I would always get this ZERO_RESULTS response.

This is the query:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=place_id:ChIJDRnPKt9TqEcRYwjmKskH6gM&destinations=place_id:ChIJ5yKvQGbEyIARRrDnL_5KOqk&key=XYZ&mode=transit ( I have censored my API key ).

Answer (score -1):

Apparently this is the intended functionality of Google and Distance Matrix API / Directions API, to not return results because it means crossing the ocean.

There is a feature request, to add this information for traveling with the airplane, but there is no concrete date.

Here you can find more information: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185005253